# Null pointer exception on method

Tags: java

This is my first every java project.All was going well and my program compiled.
I got a 3D looking object on my screen.
But when I use my moveTo(int x,int y) method I get a null pointer exception.
I've looked it up and it's obviously a huge issue for a lot of people.
But I still can't grasp the concept of it and any of the fixes that worked for other people
don't seem to fit my program.
I have tried using if statements to check for null and stuff like that but I can't get the syntax right or something.
for example the base is an ellipse , the ellipse class has a moveTo(x,y) method.but when I call on it using base.moveTo(x,y) im getting the error.
Can anybody help?
cylinder1.moveTo(8, 8);
    Exception occurred.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Cylinder3D.moveTo(Cylinder3D.java:57)
Is this what you ment by stack trace?
Here is the code for the moveTo method in the rectangle class.
public void moveTo(int x, int y)
    {
        xPosition = x;
        yPosition = y;
        makeVisible();
        draw();
    }

```
public class Cylinder3D
{   

    private int diameter;
    private int height;
    private Ellipse top;
    private Ellipse base;
    private Rectangle wall;
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;


    public Cylinder3D(int diameter, int height)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        Ellipse top = new Ellipse();
        int xdiameter=diameter;
        int ydiameter=diameter/2;
        int xPosition = 0;
        int yPosition = 0;
        top.setState(xdiameter,ydiameter,xPosition,yPosition,"black");

        Ellipse base = new Ellipse();
        int yPositionBase = yPosition + height;
        base.setState(xdiameter,ydiameter,xPosition,yPositionBase,"black");


        Rectangle wall = new Rectangle();
        int xSideLenght = diameter;
        int ySideLenght = height;
        int yPositionWall = yPosition + (diameter/4);
        wall.setState(xSideLenght,ySideLenght,xPosition,yPositionWall,"black");
        //....

    }



    public void moveTo(int x, int y)
    {
        wall.moveTo(x,y); //here is where I get the error.
        base.moveTo(x,y);
        top.moveTo(x,y);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I get a null pointer exception" -- Please post the stacktrace

Comment: What does `Rectangle wall = new Rectangle();` in your **constructor** do, given that you've already declared an instance variable of the same name?

Comment: Also post the code for wall.moveto() its possible that its trying to use some unintialized variable

Comment: Defining local variables in your member functions (e.g. constructor) shadowing class variables is a bad thing to do. It leads to many bugs, like here.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I've updated the question with some more info. Sortirios I think it just creates a rectangle for me the constructor seems to work ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor does not touch any of your member variables `top`, `base` and `wall`, because local variables declared in your constructor shadow the member variables you probably want to initialise.

Thus, they stay `null`, and trying to call member functions on them in `moveTo` throws.

Comment: +1 but you're speaking like an experienced programmer. I'll bet the OP's pulling out a dictionary right about now to understand what you just wrote...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your comment means Deduplicator. If you could break it down for me in lamens terms that would be great.

Comment: Java zeroes all object before calling the constructor. Your constructor should then set all member variables appropriately. Yours does not, because instead of assigning to your members, you define a local variable of the same name in your constructor and assign that. The local shadows the member, which thus stays zeroed, aka `null` for pointers. Using `null` where an object is expected leads to the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I managed to fix the code and what you were saying now makes sense. The lines of code that fixed it for me were. this.top=new Ellipse(); etc.. I now know I was creating a local variable top that could now be seen outside that method.